# Most efficient way to store a large amount of data in a database

Tags: c++, database, qt, optimization

In my current application, I will receive over 2000 frame per second, each one of them contain 1024(channel)*32 bit of data. I need a way to store them In a database, or maybe a CSV file. The application won't run all the day, 365 day per year. The only purpose is to test some integrated circuit (will maybe run for few min).

I am currently using the QT framework to show the data, but it also got database capability. Maybe using qt + sqlite...

How to manage such problem? Should I do a table with column = 1 (frame number) + NUMBER OF CHANNEL, and with as many row as frame? Should I simply do a table with column = 1 (frame number) + 1 (channel number) + 1 channel value?

Is writing in a CSV file would be faster and more efficient? The more I take time to write my data(either in a CSV, or trough interaction with a database), the more the graph lag. I am trying to keep this simple, but still efficient. (Avoiding multi-threading, semaphore and mutex). I have some real time constraint, the graph need to be in real-time. Every X frame (maybe every 25 frame) the graph will be updated, but at every data entry, I need to log it into some file or database.

Comment: Do you really need to programmatically interact/display your data in real time?  It sounds like you're trying to grab some quick data and do some visualizations on the output.  I'd recommend a simple CSV file that you could then inject into Microsoft Excel.  From there you get all of the DB like functions you need to filter/manipulate/display the data without having to deal with programming a one-off solution for your testing. 

Here's a quick/dirty example of writing the file.
[https://forum.qt.io/topic/16586/how-to-write-csv-file-in-qt/2][1]

Comment: I really need to display in real time, because the device tested is some sensor that as we interact with it we can directly see whats happen. Ten I need to log the data, so further analyses could be done. Data visualized with a heatmap like graph, where value is color, channel is vertical and frame number is horizontal

Comment: The fastest way would be to stream your frames in binary format to a log file. You will need to write at about 8 Mb/s then, which looks fine even with HDD.

Comment: Can you also log what you are doing when you "interact with it" so you can display both the input and output together during post processing?  If not, adding timestamps to the log data is useful.  Since your framerate is so high, just timestamp the top of the file (or put the timestamp in the file name) and you can calculate the time-value for each frame in the CSV records using your sample rate.

Comment: Data streamed directly trough UDP (so in binary and not in string format), at very very high speed. What type of log are you talking about? CSV? Database? text file?

Comment: @James Fegan So you seem to say that CSV would be the best bet. And I never intended to put a timestamp, just a frame number to facilitate indexing. Sample rate being determined by hardware side with a calibrated PLL.

Comment: My answer got downvoted so perhaps I misjudged your SW skills.  If you're determined to create a brand new GUI program for this that reads AND displays sensor data then be prepared for multithreading and mutexes regardless of how you log it.  Databases are handy for post processing, but the graphing widget is also going to store a copy of the data while displaying it, so you don't really need a DB.  UDP broadcasting the data with QT's UdpClient could help you avoid mutex locking with three non-threaded applications that perform one function (e.g. sensor-publisher-app, log-app, graph-app).

Comment: To be more clear: I'd split the graphing and logging portions into two separate components that each feed from the same sensor source rather than sensor writing to log (or DB) and then graph querying from the log/DB.  The graphing component is going to need to know how to parse the incoming data to split out channels, frame#s, etc.

Comment: @slava, in my first comment, i think I didn't understand well your idea, but now I think i do. Yo uwhere not talking about receiving data in binary format, but storing them in binary format. So while a CSV would contain the string "123" to represent the number 123, I could store it directly in a binary file, and thus avoid parsing and less overhead and HDD access. On my first entry in such file, I could put a 32 bit number representing how many frame there is in the file, then put each frame one after another. Then I would need to update the frame number each time.

Comment: yep. now you got me right. And you do not need to put the number of frames into the log file.

Comment: @James Fegan: Doing threading with QT does not seem that hard. From that page : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html it seem I just need to create a QObject and a QThread And pass the Qobject to the thread. Then it raise the question : How could I pass one frame of data to the thread handling the file. Not with the signal (signal is fine for flagging there is data, but not to transfer over 1024 32bit of data...). Is there are some sort of data structure or way to transfer buffer from thread to thread?

Answer (score -1):

If you need real-time visualization of a data stream, but are uncertain how to implement mutexes or how to represent your data, I think you need to rely more heavily on third-party tools.  I suggest writing your data using a single CSV file/channel and then displaying it elsewhere.  Microsoft Excel is really powerful for filtering/displaying data and it is trivial to import CSV files into it.  You can also link the graph to a file and update the output manually, but you won't get the ~80Hz refresh rate you're asking for... more like 1/60th Hz.

I did a quick google search and found this live-graph tool that seems to offer what you need.  Your QT application can write the CSV file and save periodically, and live-graph can display it.

[live-graph](https://sourceforge.net/projects/live-graph/)